# valueError in wordnet of nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to calculate the synsets of some chinese words. All goes well except for certain words. My code is very simple and here goes :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
syn_list = wn.synsets(u'节日', lang='cmn')
```

Here is the error information :

```
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1162, in of2ss
    return self.synset_from_pos_and_offset(of[-1], int(of[:8]))

File ".../python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1382, in synset_from_pos_and_offset
    synset = self._synset_from_pos_and_line(pos, data_file_line)

File ".../python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py", line 1512, in _synset_from_pos_and_line
    sense_index = offsets.index(synset._offset)

ValueError: 5171145 is not in list
```

Any ideas ? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

These cryptic errors may be the result of using the old WNDB format which puts entries in a file at certain byte offsets. If the file changes, the byte offsets must be updated.

You might try the [Wn](https://github.com/goodmami/wn/) library (disclaimer: I wrote it), which builds a wordnet database from the newer WN-LMF format. First you need to download the wordnets and build the database. This step may take a couple minutes but it only needs to be done once.

```
$ python -m pip install wn
$ python -m wn download cmnwn
python -m wn download cmnwn
Download [##############################] (1297104/1297104 bytes) Complete
Added cmnwn:1.3+omw (Chinese Open Wordnet)
```

Then you can use it mostly like the NLTK:

```py
>>> import wn
>>> zh = wn.Wordnet(lang='zh')  # recommended to create a Wordnet object
>>> zh.synsets('节日')
[Synset('cmnwn-15183428-n'), Synset('cmnwn-15171146-n'), Synset('cmnwn-00517728-n')]
>>> zh.synsets('节日')[0].lemmas()
['假日', '公休日', '节日']
```

Note that the language code is `zh` instead of `cmn`. Also, Wn has classes for Synsets, Senses, and Words, compared to NLTK's Synsets and Lemmas. The [FAQ](https://wn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) can explain.

The Chinese wordnet is based on the Princeton WordNet and relies on it for relations (like hypernyms, hyponyms, etc.). If you want to traverse relations, you'll need to install the Princeton Wordnet (`pwn`) or the more recent English WordNet (`ewn`). You can install it from the command line as above, or from within Python:

```py
>>> zh.synsets('节日')[0].hyponyms()
[]
>>> wn.download('ewn:2020')
Download [##############################] (13643357/13643357 bytes) Complete
Added ewn:2020 (English WordNet)
>>> zh = wn.Wordnet(lang='zh', expand='ewn:2020')  # recreate zh with expanded relations
>>> len(zh.synsets('节日')[0].hyponyms())
8
>>> zh.synsets('节日')[0].hyponyms()[0].lemmas()
['宗教节日']
```